# Deleting multiple values from cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a list of items, which has two values, a name and an id. Each list item is built using data extracted from a cookie. It also has a delete button, which basically looks at the HTML, and then removes that item from the cookie. It ain't pretty, but it works dandy.

Now all of a sudden, a third value (img src) is introduced. I've therefore made a new function to create the cookie and to build the list. Life is still pretty great.

My problem arise, however, when I attempt to delete the item from the array.

**JS**

```
$('.deleteNewCookie').on('click', function () {
  var val = $(this).prev().prev().html(); // Search DOM for value

  var cookieStr = cookieData.split('|');
  createCookie('cokLocation', "", -1);
  var newCookie = '';
  $.each(cookieStr, function (index, value) {
     if (value != '') {
        var cookieAdd = value.split(',');
        if (cookieAdd[1] != val) {
           newCookie = newCookie + value + '|';
        }
     }
  });
  createCookie('cokLocation', newCookie, '300');
});
```

This is how one item in the cookie looks like:

```
ID,Name,/image.png|
```

Now, this works as intended when the markup was simpler and there was only the ID and Name, but when I click `.deleteNewCookie` now, the image sorce remains in the cookie. How would I go about deleting everything in that array (item)? Why does it apparently delete only the first two values?

**Markup**

```
<li>
  <div class="myLocImg">
    <img src="/image.png">
  </div>
  <div class="myLocInfo">
    <h3>NAME</h3>
    <span url="locationid=ID" class="btn">More details</span>
    <a class="deleteNewCookie">Remove</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

I'm somewhat reluctant to restructure my cookie (as it's being used other places), but I may be persuaded as a last resort. I'm also not using any plugins, and I am not really interested in importing any. Plain JS or jQuery solutions only, please. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sachleen/ptVgE/ It seems to be working fine. I don't really understand the issue you're having, can give an example of what happens and the expected behavior?

Comment: Oooh, downvotes makes me sad. :'( How can I improve my question?

Comment: Dunno, wasn't me. But you can clarify your question with an example :)

Comment: @sachleen I expected it to delete all values in the position containing the `name`. This worked in the old method (when there was just ID and Name). Now it deletes the two former, but leaves the third value (image source).

Comment: Did you look at my jsfiddle? Run that and tell me what you want the output to be instead of `New: ID,Foo,/image.png|`

Comment: You know, I think you may be right. It seems to be something else that messes up. I'll take another stab at it over the weekend, and let you know what I find out. Thanks for the help so far! :)

Comment: You were correct, @sachleen. There was nothing wrong with this function after all. The error was in the `createCookie()` and how the values were stored in the HTML itself. Thanks for your help — please leave an answer, and I'll give you an accept. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachleen/ptVgE) trying to reproduce issue. Code works as expected. Other parts of code are causing issue.

Issue turned out to be relating to "`createCookie()` and how the values were stored in the HTML itself."